# alarm manager to call an intent service, after on the on click of the button, it should cancel but the alarm manager keeps triggerring the service

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

The button changes at the onclick, that is why there is a flag. but the alarm manager does not stop the intent, it keeps running forever even at the onclick to cancel the alarmManager

```
if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybuttonbc);
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, IntentServices.class);
    intent.setAction("upload");
    intent.putExtra("lat", lats);
    intent.putExtra("long", longs);

    final PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pintent);
    Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "recording started!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

} else {
    flag = true;
    imagePanicButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybuttona);
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, IntentServices.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pIntent);
    Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "recording stopped!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

}
```

Comment: Do you see the `"recording stopped!"` snackbar when you click the button?  Basically, are you sure it's getting into that code?

Comment: yes i see the recording stopped

Comment: but it keeps making the intent call that is displayed to me in form of a toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the action in the Intent that was used to initially create the alarm.

Just add this line to the code that cancels the alarm:

```
intent.setAction("upload");
```

So it would look like this:

```
if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybuttonbc);
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, IntentServices.class);
    intent.setAction("upload");
    intent.putExtra("lat", lats);
    intent.putExtra("long", longs);

    final PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pintent);
    Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "recording started!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

} else {
    flag = true;
    imagePanicButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybuttona);
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, IntentServices.class);
    intent.setAction("upload"); // <-Added
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pIntent);
    Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "recording stopped!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it works like Magic, You are the best, Thumbs up